# mysql right join query returning no values

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to return the top 10 'brands' which share a 'transaction id' with the selected brand ($brand). I began with a basic query which queries 1 table with the columns id and brand.

I am now wanting to get this to work on 2 separate tables(one for transactions and products respectively), with a common field (sku).

I began with this query, to get the initial logic (credit to a stackoverflow contributor), and it works perfectly.

```
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT brand
FROM transactions
WHERE
id IN (SELECT id FROM transactions WHERE brand = :brand)
AND brand <> :brand
GROUP BY brand
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 10");
$query->bindparam(":brand", $brand);
$query->execute();
```

The above works great as I mentioned. And I modified it slightly below to incorporate related tables. BUT, it doesnt work. and returns no values.

Any takers. Much appreciated - Adam

```
$brand = $_POST['brand'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `2_products`.`brand` 
FROM `2_products` 
RIGHT JOIN `1_txns` 
ON `2_products`.`sku`=`1_txns`.`sku` 
WHERE 
`1_txns`.`txn_id` IN (SELECT `1_txns`.`txn_id` FROM `1_txns` WHERE `2_products`.`brand` = :brand) 
AND `2_products`.`brand` <> :brand 
GROUP BY `2_products`.`brand` 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 10");
$query->bindparam(":brand", $brand);
$query->execute();
```

I understand that there may be other methods to this such as create temp table, with just `txn_id` and `brand` columns, but again I'm unsure of how to do this.

edit attempt #2 - Here as per advice below I have moved the AND `2_products`.`brand` <> :brand to immediately after the ON clause. Still 0 rows returned.

```
    $brand = $_POST['brand'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `2_products`.`brand` 
FROM `2_products` 
RIGHT JOIN `1_txns` 
ON `2_products`.`sku`=`1_txns`.`sku` 
AND `2_products`.`brand` <> :brand
WHERE `1_txns`.`txn_id` IN (SELECT `1_txns`.`txn_id` FROM `1_txns` WHERE `2_products`.`brand` = :brand) 
GROUP BY `2_products`.`brand` 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 10");
$query->bindparam(":brand", $brand);
$query->execute();
```

EDIT 3:  Also taking into consideration the fact that in my inner select query the where clause is a column which is not selected from the inner query.  and so I tried this:   To which I got an error 'Operand should only contain 1 column(s)'

```
    SELECT `2_products`.`brand` 
FROM `2_products` 
RIGHT JOIN `1_txns` 
ON `2_products`.`sku`=`1_txns`.`sku` 
AND `2_products`.`brand` <> :brand 
WHERE `1_txns`.`txn_id` IN (SELECT `1_txns`.`txn_id`, `2_products`.`brand` 
                            FROM `1_txns` 
                            LEFT JOIN `2_products` 
                            ON `1_txns`.`sku`=`2_products`.`sku` 
                            WHERE `2_products`.`brand` = :brand) 
GROUP BY `2_products`.`brand` 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Your inner query is wrong. You have a column in your `where` clause whose table is not included in your `from` clause. So, it won't work.

Comment: Remove the , `2_products`.`brand` from the inner select. You can't return more than one field in your inner query. That will get rid of the error, but it's hard to pinpoint the problem without seeing the real data you have on tables.

Comment: Perhaps my inner query is the problem when trying to use this method against 2 related tables as opposed to one which just has the 2 columns? as Prerak pointed out the where clause defines a column which isn't in the inner selection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved in the following question on dba.stackexchange

[DBA Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/123401/join-query-returning-0-rows-impossible-where)

Answer (score 0):

When a `LEFT` / `RIGHT` join return no records, first check if `WHERE` has any filters referring to the table on the "weak" side. By "weak" side I mean the right table on a `LEFT JOIN`, or the left table on a `RIGHT JOIN`.

In your case, the left table is `2_products`, so it might generate NULL fields, but in `WHERE` you have `2_products.brand <> :brand`. If this condition fails, the record will be removed.

To avoid this, try moving this condition to the ON clause, after `2_products.sku=1_txns.sku`, because filtering there will not remove the record if the condition fails. It should look this way:

`ON 2_products.sku=1_txns.sku AND 2_products.brand <> :brand`

And the WHERE clause should look like this:

`WHERE 1_txns.txn_id IN (SELECT 1_txns.txn_id FROM 1_txns WHERE 2_products.brand = :brand)`

Comment: I've just had a go at this and still no records returned. Please see my edit at the bottom of the original question.  Many Thanks -A

Comment: @AdamCopley, I meant to move just the condition to the ON clause, not the whole WHERE. Please see the edit I made on my answer.

Comment: I tried your solution and still no results returned.  I also attempted something regarding Prerak Sola's comment,  and returned an error.